# Simplifying a compact proof of triangularization

Tags: linear-algebra, triangularization

I am going through this interesting paper   [A simultaneous triangularization result](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0024379515005716?token=D1F24F04E3D1A30767D84C60A03F57BCE2E90A29F444CA96E916A3AF2CCD321FDB426A96E00AA7677B730C7776C3228A&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20230411112354) by Dan Shemesh. The Theorem 2 read

> If $\textbf{A}[\textbf{A},\textbf{B}]=\textbf{0}$ and $\textbf{B}[\textbf{A},\textbf{B}]=\textbf{0}$, then matrices $\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{B}$ are simultaneously triangularizable.

However, the compactness of the proof (attached below as pic) makes it hard to follow for someone like me who is not an expert in the field.

In particular:

1. What is meant by $\textbf{C}$-invariant?
2. Why is $[\textbf{C},\textbf{D}]$ is not ivertible?
3. How is it  that $\textbf{C}\textbf{D}x_0 =\textbf{D}\textbf{C}x_0=0=\lambda \textbf{D} x_0$ implies $\textbf{D}x \in ker(\textbf{C}-\lambda \textbf{I})$?
4. Similarly the last line "And by $[\textbf{C},\textbf{D}]\textbf{D}=\textbf{0} \dots$" is not clear to me.

[image]

Comment: **(1.)** a vector space $V$ has a T-invariant subspace subspace $W\subseteq V$ when $TW\subseteq W$.  When $\dim W=1$ we call $W$'s generator an eigenvector; most proof based introductions to Linear Algebra will walk you through this. **(2.)** $\big[C,D\big]\neq \mathbf 0$... I don't know why you wrote this but I suggest you re-read the proof.  Now the **simpler**, standard simultaneous triangularization argument **is** for the case $\big[C,D\big]=\mathbf 0$ which I suggest you learn first.  The above is a generalization of the simpler case but I suspect the simpler case will be a challenge.

Comment: Thanks @user8675309, in (2.) I meant "why $[C, D]$ is not invertible".

Comment: $\det\Big(\big[C,D\big]\Big)\neq 0\implies C= \big[C,D\big]^{-1} \mathbf 0=\mathbf 0\implies \big[C,D\big]=\big[\mathbf 0,D\big]=\mathbf 0\implies \det\Big(\big[C,D\big]\Big)= 0$ which is a contradiction.  Where did you get stuck when you considered the implications of $\big[C,D\big]$ being invertible?